# All Homotheties really are homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $M$ is an $R$-module, then the lecture notes says the homothety for any $a \in R$ defined by $x \to ax$ is a homomorphism from $M\to M$ but I cannot see why.

Addition is fine but for multiplication I don't see why it satisfies $a_M(rx)=ra_M(x)$ . This might not be true unless $R$ is commutative. Right?
So I am saying that the homothety $a,M$ need not be a module homomorphism?

Comment: Correct, $x\mapsto ax$ is not a homomorphism of left $R$-modules unless $a$ is in the center of $R$. There are variants, where something works. For example, for all $b\in R$, the mapping $\rho_b:R\to R, x\mapsto xb$ is a homomorphism of left $R$-modules. Basically because associativity gives
$$\rho_b(ax)=(ax)b=a(xb)=a \rho_b(x)$$ for all $a,x$. The point being that $a$ and $b$ can here act from the opposite sides, and won't get on each others way. So called bimodules allow further generalizations.